# multiline search pattern in linux

Tags: search, awk, grep

I am trying to use grep to perform multiline search in linux but having problem with it. 
Basically i want to extract all the lines that follows with `Sequences` string in the below example.

```
Query= BRNW_157
Sequences producing significant alignments:                          (Bits)  Value
Query= BRNW_428
Query= BRNW_503
Sequences producing significant alignments:                          (Bits)  Value
Query= BRNW_601
Query= BRNW_617
Sequences producing significant alignments:                          (Bits)  Value
```

I tried awk but it doesn't work...
`awk '/Query=*/,/Sequences*/'` and then i used grep and it doesn't work either...`grep -PZo 'Query=*\n.*sequences'`.
Is there a way to go around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you want to find the word Sequences and print that line plus the line before it?

That'd just be:

```
awk '/Sequences/{print prev ORS $0} {prev=$0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for

```
grep -oPz '(?ms)Query=(?:(?!Query).)*?Sequences.*?$'
```

This passes PCRE MULTILINE and DOTALL flags via the `(?ms)` and picks out each segment from a `Query` line to the next `Sequences` line.

Additionally, the `-z` flag passed to [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) forces it to treat NUL as line-separator, ,making the contents of the file appear as a single string to it.